# LineChart JavaFX -saving to png - How to control the size

Tags: javafx, png, linechart

I cannot figure out how to control the size of the LineChart saved to png. The chart looks great on the screen, in it's own window, but it gets scrunched vertically when saved. I've tried to figure out how to control the size, but to no avail. It must be a simple setting, but...

Any help would be appreciated.

With the following code, excluding the code that sets the data values:

```
LineChart<Number, Number> xyChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

StackPane layout = new StackPane();
layout.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
xyChart.prefWidthProperty().bind(window.widthProperty());
xyChart.prefHeightProperty().bind(window.heightProperty());
layout.getChildren().add(xyChart);

VBox mainVBox = new VBox();
mainVBox.getChildren().addAll(menuHBox, layout);

Scene scene = new Scene(mainVBox, 800, 600);
window.setScene(scene);
xyChart.setAnimated(false);
WritableImage snapShot = scene.snapshot(null);
try {
ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapShot, null), "png", new File("test3.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

The chart as displayed on the screen is 
[window grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsJvh.png)

whereas the png file that is written is
[upload of the png file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVB6X.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try saving the image **after** the window is shown, as layouts and sizes are computed on a required basis, and may not give the same values before.

Another solution would - of course - be to explicitly set the preferred size of the node.

```
xyChart.setPrefWidth(...);
xyChart.setPrefHeight(...);
```

The reason why bindings don't help is because the window itself doesn't have the computed size yet, as previously said.

Comment: Yes, thanks, showing the window first solved the problem!

Comment: Also note, that you can manually trigger a layout using [parent.applyCss(); parent.layout();](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#applyCss--).